# How do I show all validation errors from the modx register snippet?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution

How do I show all validation errors from the modx register snippet?

Right now if I want to show all possible errors in my form I have to do something like this:

```
[[+error.message:notempty=`[[+error.message]]<br>`]]
[[+error.username:notempty=`[[+error.username]]<br>`]]
[[+error.password:notempty=`[[+error.password]]<br>`]]
[[+error.password_confirm:notempty=`[[+error.password_confirm]]<br>`]]
[[+error.email:notempty=`[[+error.email]]<br>`]]
[[+error.salutation:notempty=`[[+error.salutation]]<br>`]]
[[+error.firstname:notempty=`[[+error.firstname]]<br>`]]
[[+error.lastname:notempty=`[[+error.lastname]]<br>`]]
[[+error.institution:notempty=`[[+error.institution]]<br>`]]
[[+error.excountry:notempty=`[[+error.excountry]]<br>`]]
[[+error.province:notempty=`[[+error.province]]<br>`]]
[[+error.provinceother:notempty=`[[+error.provinceother]]<br>`]]
[[+error.excity:notempty=`[[+error.excity]]<br>`]]
[[+error.oncologist-database:notempty=`[[+error.oncologist-database]]<br>`]]
```

Does anyone know if there is a placeholder that just dumps all errors?

Comment: Your question actually helped me work around this same problem. I don't know why the error messages aren't all input into the error.message placeholder, but the individual ones worked perfectly for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You say little to nothing about how the errors are generated in the snippet.

There are two approcahes to this. You could make the entire error-message into one in the snippet. That way you can simply concatenate them there. It would only require one placeholder in the chunk.

Or you could supply all the error-messages every time the chunk is displayed. The change is that when there are no error-messages, the placeholder is just empty (that way, you don't need to test with `notempty`). You could also make `<br />` a part of the error-string itself. That way you don't need the query at all and you could just list each of the error-messages after each other. It would be "cleaner" in the chunk, but I prefer the first solution.